# Tangent of the angle between a field and the ordinate axis

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

The following is a (heavy) paraphrase from page 19 of the book *Ordinary Differential Equation* by *Arnol'd*

> Consider the equation $x'(t) = v(x(t)), x \in \mathbb{R}$. The RHS defines a phase velocity vector field: a vector $v(x)$ is attached at the point $x$. Assume that $v(x)$ is continuous and never vanishes. The tangent of the angle between our field and the x-axis equals $1/v(x)$.

My question is is that why is the tangent of the angle between a general vector field and the ordinate axis equal to $1/v(x)$? The author provides no derivation for his claim, and I have been unable to find a derivation for the angle from the Internet.

Comment: Draw an arbitrary vector in the $x$ $t$ plane. The slope of that vector is $\mathrm dx/\mathrm dt$ (by definition equaling $v(x)$). Could you then reason what the tangent between that vector and the $x$-axis is using a triangle?

Comment: @Eli It is sometimes the simplest things that can trip you over. Thanks! To check my reasoning: Given the vector $v(x)$, we are interested in the angle $\eta = (\pi/2) - \phi$, where $\phi = \arctan(dx/dt)$. However since the triangle formed by $v(x), dt, dx$ is a right-triangle, it follows that $\tan(\eta) = dt/dx$.